# Can I add a DataMember to a CollectionDataContract in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a collection class that I have decorated with a CollectionDataContract.  The collection class also has a property on the class that I would like to be passed to the service client.  I have tried adding [DataMember] to that property but it didn't add it to the class in the client when I updated.

Any WCF experts out there have any help to offer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A working solution is posted on my blog:

http://borismod.blogspot.com/2009/04/wcf-collectiondatacontract-and.html

UPD: Thanks, for your comment, Jeff. 
Here is a summary here of a non generic class. A full generic solution can be found in a new post in my blog: 
http://borismod.blogspot.com/2009/06/v2-wcf-collectiondatacontract-and.html

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]    
public class EntityCollectionWorkaround : ICollection 
    {

        #region Constructor
        public EntityCollectionWorkaround()
        {
            Entities = new List();
        } 
        #endregion

        [DataMember]
        public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List Entities { get; set; }

        #region ICollection Members
          // Implement here members of ICollection by wrapping Entities methods
        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members
          // Implement here members of IIEnumerable by wrapping Entities methods
        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: Good blog post, but it would be nice if you gave a quick summary here.

Comment: Doesn't this expose an `<Entities>` element in the XML? The preferable solution would be to have `AdditionalProperty` as an XML attribute of `EntityCollectionWorkaround` and then have each `<Entity>` element as a direct child of `EntityCollectionWorkaround`. But I guess this is impossible with DataContract serialization?

Comment: Yes, it does, but don't see what's wrong with this? I suppose that your suggestion implies that some kind of XML serialization is used. I prefer separating the serialization method (binary, xml or whatever) and class definition. Even though if we adopt your suggestion, AdditionalProperty will be exposed in XML.

Comment: +1 for a great solution! I was so stuck thinking I need to use the `CollectionDataContract` for the collection to serialize. And with `IXmlSerializable` I was going to have to manually handle so much of the serialization that `DataContractSerializer` was going to be worthless to me. This answer was difficult for me to find, so I elaborated on my solution using your answer an posted it as a new answer below. Hopefully it will be easier for someone else to find later.

Comment: I am glad that you find my 5 years old answer useful :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider implementing custom serialization for your class.  It might be easiest to implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx), output the values of your custom property and then use the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to serialize instances of the child items in the collection to the output.

Comment: For my case, `IXmlSerializable` would work, but the structures inside the collection were large, and once I implemented `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` in the collection, I was going to have to manually write everything below that in the hierarchy... at which point I might as well custom roll the entire thing. I added an answer below describing how I got around `IXmlSerializable` by using the normal `DataContract` attribute on the collection.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is intended as an add-on to the answer @BorisModylevsky gave. Every solution I could find to this issue suggested using `IXmlSerializable`. But here is my issue: I have a hierarchical parent-child structure like this

```
public class Project 
{
    //Several properties here...

    public ItemCollection Items { get; private set; }

    public Project() 
    { 
        Items = new ItemCollection();
    }
}

public class ItemCollection : IList<ItemDetails>
{
    private List<ItemDetails> _list =  new List<ItemDetails>();

    public Project Parent { get; private set; }

    ///dependency injection...
    public ItemCollection(Project parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    //Interface methods here working with _list...
    //In the `Add(ItemDetails item)` method, I update incoming items with item.Parent = this.Parent.
}

public class ItemDetails
{
    public Project Parent { get; set; }

    //Several properties here, including some sub classes

    ///dependency injection...
    public ItemDetails(Project parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

In order to make this work for [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) I had to add some private constructors, and the needed attributes:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Project 
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public ItemCollection Items { get; private set; }

    //[DataMember(Order=##)]
    //Several properties here, including some other sub classes

    public Project() 
    { 
        Items = new ItemCollection();
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class ItemCollection : IList<ItemDetails>
{
    private List<ItemDetails> _list = new List<ItemDetails>();

    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public Project Parent { get; private set; }

    ///dependency injection...
    public ItemCollection(Project parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    //Private constructor for use with DataContractSerializer
    private ItemCollection() { }

    //Interface methods here working with _list...
}

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class ItemDetails
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public Project Parent { get; private set; }

    //[DataMember(Order=##)]
    //Several properties here, including some sub classes

    ///dependency injection...
    public ItemDetails(Project parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    //Private constructor for use with DataContractSerializer
    private ItemDetails() { }
}
```

The problem is that the XML is created for the collection looked like this:

```
<Project>
    <!--OTHER PROJECT PROPERTIES HERE-->
    <Items z:Id="i11">
        <ItemDetails z:Id="i12">
            <Parent z:Ref="i1"/>
            <!--OTHER PROPERTIES HERE-->
        </ItemDetails>
        <ItemDetails z:Id="i16">
            <Parent z:Ref="i1"/>
            <!--OTHER PROPERTIES HERE-->
        </ItemDetails>
    </Items>
</Project>
```

There is no `Parent` property under `Items` in the XML. Best I can tell, `CollectionDataContract` does not support any additional properties in the collection class.

In this case, if I implemented `IXmlSerializable` like so many had suggested, then I was going to be stuck manually serializing and deserializing a huge amount of the structures inside ItemDetails (that I have not shown here for brevity sake). In which case, DataContractSerializer was going to be nearly worthless to me.

But with @BorisModylevsky answer above, I changed the code up to this:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Project 
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public ItemCollection Items { get; private set; }

    //[DataMember(Order=##)]
    //Several properties here, including some other sub classes

    public Project() 
    { 
        Items = new ItemCollection();
    }
}

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class ItemCollection : IList<ItemDetails>
{
    //Refactored _list to ItemsList. I didn't have to; I could have used [DataMember(Name="ItemsList", Order=1)]
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    private List<ItemDetails> ItemsList = new List<ItemDetails>();

    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public Project Parent { get; private set; }

    ///dependency injection...
    public ItemCollection(Project parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    //Private constructor for use with DataContractSerializer
    private ItemCollection() { }

    //Interface methods here working with ItemsList...
}

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class ItemDetails
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public Project Parent { get; private set; }

    //[DataMember(Order=##)]
    //Several properties here, including some sub classes

    ///dependency injection...
    public ItemDetails(Project parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    //Private constructor for use with DataContractSerializer
    private ItemDetails() { }
}
```

To summarize: I changed `CollectionDataContract` to `DataContract` and added `DataMember` to the private list I am using in the collection. This works since `DataContractSerializer` can get and set private properties/fields. And now the XML looks like this:

```
<Project>
    <!--OTHER PROJECT PROPERTIES HERE-->
    <Items z:Id="i11">
        <Parent z:Ref="i1"/>
        <ItemsList>
            <ItemDetails z:Id="i12">
                <Parent z:Ref="i1"/>
                <!--OTHER PROPERTIES HERE-->
            </ItemDetails>
            <ItemDetails z:Id="i16">
                <Parent z:Ref="i1"/>
                <!--OTHER PROPERTIES HERE-->
            </ItemDetails>
        </ItemsList>
    </Items>
</Project>
```

Which for my purposes works perfectly. It serializes and deserializes as needed.